# Problema com node js ao enviar arquivos para banco de dados mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, react

Estou com um formulário em React Js mas ao enviar o body para o node, apenas a imagem não funciona. Porém ao fazer o post pelo insônia, tudo funciona perfeitamente. O console.log(req.file) quando postado pelo react retorna undefined e quando pelo insônia retorna normalmente.*O banco de dados está no MySql*

**Código do React**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import {Container} from './styles.js'
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from 'yup'

let validationRegister=yup.object().shape({
  cpf:yup.string("CPF inválido").required("Campo obrigatório").min(11,"CPF inválido").typeError('Insira os dados corretamente'),
  nome:yup.string("Nome inválido").required("Campo obrigatório"),
  marca:yup.string("Marca inválida").required("Campo obrigatório"),
  ano:yup.number("Ano inválido").required("Campo obrigatório").typeError('Insira os dados corretamente'),
  quilometragem:yup.number("kM inválida").required("Campo obrigatório"),
  preco:yup.number("Preço inválido").required("Campo obrigatório").typeError('Insira os dados corretamente'),
  imagem: yup.mixed().test('fileType', 'Formato de arquivo inválido', (value) => {
    return !value || (value && ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'].includes(value[0].type));
  }),
})

export const FormAnuncio = () => {
  const[message,setMessage]=useState("")

  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
    resolver:yupResolver(validationRegister)
  });

  const onSubmit=data=>cadastro(data)

  function cadastro(data){
    console.log(data)
    const url="http://localhost:8081/criaranuncio"
    setMessage("Anúncio criado!")
    fetch(url,{
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
      },
      body:JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then((resp)=>{resp.json()})
    .catch((e)=>{
      console.log("Houve um erro: "+e)
      return
    })
  } 

  return (
    <Container>
      {message.length>0?<div className='ErroDiv'><h4>{message}</h4></div>:" "}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} encType="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="imagem">Imagem do veículo</label>
          <input type="file" name='imagem' {...register('imagem')}/>
          {errors.imagem && <span>{errors.imagem.message}</span>}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="cpf">CPF</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder='O CPF deve ser o mesmo vínculado a conta' name='cpf' {...register('cpf')}/>
          {errors.cpf && <span>{errors.cpf.message}</span>}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="nome">Nome do veículo</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder='Insira o nome do veículo' name='nome' {...register('nome')}/>
          {errors.nome && <span>{errors.nome.message}</span>}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="marca">Marca</label>
          <select name='marca' {...register("marca")}>
            <option value=" ">Selecione</option>
            <option value="chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
            <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
            <option value="ford">Ford</option>
            <option value="volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
            <option value="renault">Renault</option>
            <option value="honda">Honda</option>
            <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
            <option value="hyundai">Hyundai</option>
          </select>
          {errors.marca && <span>{errors.marca.message}</span>}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="ano">Ano do veículo</label>
          <input type="number" placeholder='Insira o ano do veículo' name='ano' {...register('ano')}/>
          {errors.ano && <span>{errors.ano.message}</span>}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="quilometragem">Quilometragem do veículo</label>
          <input type="number" placeholder='Insira a quilometragem do veículo' name='quilometragem' {...register('quilometragem')}/>
          {errors.quilometragem && <span>{errors.quilometragem.message}</span>}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="preco">Valor a ser anunciado</label>
          <input type="number" placeholder='Insira o valor' name='preco' {...register('preco')}/>
          {errors.preco && <span>{errors.preco.message}</span>}
        </div>
        <button type='submit'>Anunciar</button>
      </form>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

**Código do node**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser')
const mysql=require('mysql')
const multer = require('multer');
const path=require('path')
//Cors
const cors=require('cors')

//Config multer

const app=express()
app.use(cors())
const port=8081

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded())

const connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'',
    database:'reactautos'
})


//Conexão com banco de dados
connection.connect((err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.error("Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados: "+ err.stack)
        return
    }
    console.log("Conexão estabelecida com sucesso!")
})

//Criação de imagem
const storage=multer.diskStorage({
    destination:path.join(__dirname,'../public','upload'),
    filename:function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,Date.now()+ '-' + file.originalname)
    }
})

//Cria anúncio
app.post("/criaranuncio",async(req,res)=>{
    const {cpf,nome,marca,ano,quilometragem,preco} = req.body
    
    let upload=multer({storage:storage}).single('imagem')
    
    try {
        upload(req,res,(err)=>{
            console.log(req.file)


            if(!req.file){
                return res.send("Retorne uma imagem válida!")
            }else if(err){
                return res.send(err)
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    
})
```

Comment: `body:JSON.stringify(data)`, você está convertendo um formulário que possui um arquivo para JSON?

Comment: Tem dezenas de perguntas que tratam desse problema aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bajax%5D+upload, pode dar uma olhada nas respostas